# How to pass argument at runtime?

Tags: c#, lamar

We're migrating from StructureMap to Lamar but I could not find the "Lamar version" for passing arguments at runtime.

We have a class that requires a string argument (pseudo code):

```
public class MyRepository {
  public MyRepository(string accountId) {}
}
```

… and a factory

```
public class MyRepoFactory(Container container) {
  public MyRepository GetRepositoryForAccount(string accountId) => 
     container
        // With() is not available in Lamar?
        .With("accountId").EqualTo(accountId)
        .GetInstance<IMyRepository>();
}
```

In reality there are additional dependencies.

How can a say Lamar `GetInstance()` for `IMyRepository` and use value xy for constructor argument named `accountId`?

Answer (score 2):

I see two approaches with Lamar.

**Using properties**

While Lamar doesn't offer `With()`, a workaround might be to make the account a property you set in the factory method, or to have the factory simply get all the repository's dependencies manually from the container. It is, after all, a factory, so tying it closely to the type it produces seems fine from a design standpoint.

**Using Contexts**

A nicer approach might be to set the accountId in a context and use the context in the repository:

```
public class ExecutionContext
{
    public Guid AccountId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
}
```

The repository looks like this

```
public class MyRepository
{
    public ExecutionContext Context { get; }

    public MyRepository(ExecutionContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }
}
```

Make the context injectable...

```
var container = new Container(_ =>
{
    _.Injectable<ExecutionContext>();
});
```

and then, in your factory...

```
public MyRepository GetRepositoryForAccount(string accountId) {
    var nested = container.GetNestedContainer();
    var context = new ExecutionContext{ AccountId = accountId };
    nested.Inject(context);
    return nested.GetInstance<IMyRepository>()
}
```

Documentation: https://jasperfx.github.io/lamar/documentation/ioc/injecting-at-runtime/

You also might want to consider if you really need the factory in this scenario, of if using the nested, injectable container directly perhaps makes for a cleaner design.

Comment: Thanks @adhominem. While this answer shows good ways to solve the problem, I'm still hoping that someone has an "as easy as it was with StructureMap" solution.

Answer (score 0):

Rude but easy solution could be next code:

```
var type = container.Model.DefaultTypeFor(typeof(IMyRepository));
var constructor = type.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(string) });
var instance = constructor.Invoke(new object[] { accountId });
return (IMyRepository)instance;
```